# if else in a for loop to check conditions inside an array

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

i am using splashkit library for c++ and have a change name function, ideally once the user inputs the values in the array names[i], then when using this we are trying to check if the input value already exists if it exists then select that value and replace it with the user input.

In case the user input does not match any of the array names[] then it should display a message like(Sorry try again or sorry this value doesn't match with any listed values).

my code is only working properly when i have two same array values then it recognises the input and let the user change the value to a new value. if i have 3 different values stored in array it is not checking the conditions and not working as intended.

```
void change_name(string names[], string name , int size)
{
    int i;
    i = 0;
   
    //Declare variables
    //your code(s) and your own comment here

    //ask them to enter the name to change
    //your code(s) and your own comment here *What data type?

    //Check the name is in the array 
    //your code(s) and your own comment here  *What data type?

    // your code(s) and your own comment here 
    write_line("Which name would you like to change: ");
    name = read_string(" Name: ");
    
//  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
//  {
        if(name != names[i])
        {
             write_line("Sorry this option does not exist");
            //names [i] = read_string(" Name: ");
        }
        else if (name == names[i])
        {
            write_line("Please enter a name: ");
            names[i] = read_string(" Name: ");
        }
   //}    
}
```

Comment: Why is the `for` statement commented out? Are you using `std::string` or some other type like I suspect the CS50 fake strings?

Comment: Loop over the array once and store a `foundIndex` or similar when the name matches. Initialize it to an invalid value before the loop so you know if the name wasn't found. For example, the value `-1` or `size` would be reasonable "not-found" values. After the loop, you now have the index and can take either of the two appropriate actions. Note that the `else` here does not require an `else if`. No need to duplicate and invert logic.

Answer (score -1):

```
void change_name(string names[], string name , int size)
{
    
    int i;
    i= 0;
    write_line("Which name would you like to change: ");
    name = read_string(" Name: ");
    
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
       {
    
          if (name == names[i])
            {
               write_line("Please enter a name: ");
               names[i] = read_string(" Name: ");
            }
       }
       if(i==SIZE)
       {
   
          write_line("Sorry this option does not exist");
       }
}
```

Comment: What is the source of the OP's issue? How does this solve the problem? _Does_ it solve the problem? This answer would benefit from elaboration.

Comment: this does work , but there is a small issue which I was having before as well , The terminal out is like this-    Enter a name: Sourabh
Enter a name: Akhsay
Enter a name: ABhishek
Sourabh
Akhsay
ABhishek
Total length: 21
Longest name
ABhishek
Index: 2
Which name would you like to change: 
 Name: Akhsay
Please enter a name: 
 Name: Sourabh
Sorry this option does not exist
Sourabh
Sourabh
ABhishek                                    ----- here even if the value is matches the value of array and is allowing us to chnage value. It still show ("sorry this opt..)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to add an explanation, and note that `if(i==SIZE)` is always true.